# SDL Web 8.5 - Systematically unlock content (Component/Page/Bundle) locked by disabled user

Tags: web8, cme, gui-extensions, event-system, web8.5

We have business requirement to implement a feature where the system can unlock content locked by a disabled user:

1. user who has left the organization once their ID gets deactivated from Tridion. (Along with this we would like to give partial permission to authors to unlock content which are checked out by disabled user)
2. Possibly unlock items locked and idle by active users for more than 72 hours.  These content should not be in workflow.

**Unlock for the following use cases**

- Content has not been edited or saved but user has exited out of
  content - Unlock after 3 days.
- User has been de-activiated - Unlock once user has been de-activiated
  The system should do this unlocking on a daily basis during
  off-business hours OR when the user is being de-activated.

Looking for valuable solution and ideas for above business requirement.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, permissions for unlocking items locked by any user are added in Web 8.5 as part of the Privileges feature. See https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-20CF76FE-5FC5-486D-8281-9C5CFDA2EAA2

So if you configure your Privileges for users correctly, you can have non admin users perform this task already.

There is no scheduling of tasks in Tridion at this time, so for that you will have to find your own solution, a program or service which runs at scheduled intervals that can use the Core Service API to unlock the items of deactivated users, and items which have been locked for more than 3 days.

Comment: Are you sure? I think privileges for this were added in 8.2 or 8.3, which made it out to the 8.5 release. See Alvin's series of posts on this topic: https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/b/blog-posts/posts/sdl-web-privileges-1-of-3

Comment: @NunoLinhares Just checked and you are right actually, privileges are already available in Web 8.5, I'll change my answer later today.